# Can I regard the ”particular“ as extraordinary and the "peculiar" as distinct ？

Tags: uso-de-palabras, sinónimos, diferencias-entre-palabras

What is the difference between "peculiar" and "particular" in meaning and usage?

Comment: Have you tried looking them up in a dictionary?

Comment: Sure I have looked up the DEL . I also look them up in Baidu.com.

Comment: In fact, I am neither from a English-speaking country nor a Germanic languages country and  Romance languages country. Both the two source language are difficult for me to understand.Please try to read me.

Comment: You should understand that there are cases where, unless you provide examples, it won't be possible to get an accurate answer. "Particular" and "peculiar" share some meanings and do not share others.

Answer (score 1):

Looking in the DLE we find for [peculiar](https://dle.rae.es/peculiar?m=form) just the single definition

1. adj. Propio o privativo de cada persona o cosa.

For [particular](https://dle.rae.es/particular?m=form) the position is rather different as we have many definitions.

> 1. adj. Propio y privativo de algo, o que le pertenece con singularidad.
> 2. adj. Especial, extraordinario, o pocas veces visto en su línea.
> 3. adj. Singular o individual, como contrapuesto a universal o general.
> 4. adj. Dicho de una persona: Que no tiene título o cargo oficial que la distinga de otras. U. t. c. s. Este piso lo vende un particular.
> 5. adj. Privado, que no es de propiedad o uso públicos.
> 6. adj. Dicho de un acto: Extraoficial o privado, aunque es realizado por una persona con cargo o carácter oficial o público.

So we see some extended uses but also considerable overlap with *peculiar*

Obviously we now need to investigate further

[propio](https://dle.rae.es/propio#Cx4ayHl) occurs in both of the definitions above

> 1. adj. Que pertenece de manera exclusiva a alguien. Tienen embarcadero propio.
> 2. adj. Característico, peculiar de cada persona o cosa. Esas preguntas son propias de un niño.

[privativo](https://dle.rae.es/privativo?m=form) also occurs in both

> 2. adj. Propio y peculiar singularmente de alguien o algo, y no de otros.
>    bienes privativos

Confirming the considerable overlap in their meanings.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to understand the difference is when they are used together:

- Es una peculiar particularidad = It's a special particularity

> Samantha Ramsdell de 31 años es toda una celebridad en redes sociales por su **peculiar particularidad**. Rompió el Récord Guinnes por tener la boca abierta mas grande del mundo en una mujer.

<sub>*Source [msn.com](https://www.msn.com/es-cl/noticias/otras/r%C3%A9cord-guinness-por-la-boca-abierta-m%C3%A1s-grande-del-mundo-lo-que-te-hace-%C3%BAnico-es-tu-s%C3%BAperpoder/ar-AAMMEvA)*</sub>

Comment: ummmm... Sorry, Could you please explian it more?